# Does any one know how to expand queries using Wordnet with Lucene 3.6?

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval, wordnet

I've found the class **WordnetSynonymParser** in org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym but there aren't examples of its usage neither in the API nor in google. Does any one have experience with it?

Thank you!

**EDIT**: I know that there used to be the class [SynExpand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248039/synonyms-using-lucene), but with version 3.6 it disappeared...

I try:

```
           try {
                   FileReader rulesReader = new FileReader("wn/wn_s.pl");
               SynonymMap.Builder parser = null;
               parser = new WordnetSynonymParser(true, true, analyzer);
               ((WordnetSynonymParser)parser).add(rulesReader);          
               synonymMap = parser.build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.exit(1);
            }
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Invalid synonym rule at line 109
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.WordnetSynonymParser.add(WordnetSynonymParser.java:75)
        at pirServer.QueryClassifier.<init>(QueryClassifier.java:77)
        at pirServer.PIRServer.main(PIRServer.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: term: course of action analyzed to a token with posinc != 1
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymMap$Builder.analyze(SynonymMap.java:131)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.WordnetSynonymParser.parseSynonym(WordnetSynonymParser.java:92)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.WordnetSynonymParser.add(WordnetSynonymParser.java:67)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: Is it possible to perform query expansion by wordnet with lucene 3.6??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on a similar thing and just read the documentation - so a relevant caution from the SynonymFilter doc is very fresh:

""This token stream cannot properly handle position increments != 1, ie, you should place this filter before filtering out stop words""

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html

It's possible that the analyzer you're passing (which you fail to describe in your post) to the WordNetSynonymParser does remove stop words (as is the case for most of them) causing:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: term: course of action analyzed to a token with posinc != 1

Answer (score 3):

Edi Bice answer helped resolve the issue for me.  For others who might be looking, with lucene 4.0, initialize parser with empty char set

```
WordnetSynonymParser parse = new WordnetSynonymParser(true, true, new StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET));
```