# Query expansion by ontology with Lucene 3.6?

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

Is it possible to perform query expansion with Lucene 3.6 using any ontology? I've been looking for doing this using [WordNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047466/does-any-one-know-how-to-expand-queries-using-wordnet-with-lucene-3-6) but I didn't found nothing:

Thanks

Comment: It was implemented for Wordnet in Lucene for older versions: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/api/contrib-wordnet/org/apache/lucene/wordnet/SynExpand.html#expand%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer,%20java.lang.String,%20float%29. But I've been using the 3.6, why should they have removed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an analyzer that includes [SynonymFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) when parsing your query. You might want to use [WordnetSynonymParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/WordnetSynonymParser.html) when parsing the synonyms from Wordnet.